# Interface de projetos GIT para servidor local

Tags: git, github

Bom dia,

Estou em busca de uma interface de administração GIT para um servidor Linux (Debian para ser mais específico), onde no mesmo ficará o repositórios dos projetos da empresa. Pesquisei e encontrei várias na internet, porém nenhuma onde os recursos possam a ser comparados ao GitHub.

O repositório dos projetos será localhost por isso a necessidade para administração local dos projetos.

Comment: Anderson, procure por GitLab. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução mais adotada nesses casos é o [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/). Você configura um servidor web local, instala o GitLab nele, configura os usuários, inicializa os repositórios e então sobe os repositórios locais para os repositórios remotos do GitLab.

Entretanto, a instalação do GitLab não é trivial, o que faz com que muita gente acabe optando pelos planos corporativos do GitHub, em que você pode adicionar times e repositórios privados.

Cada um deles tem seu *trade-off*. Adotando o GitLab você economiza com os planos do GitHub e garante que seus projetos terão privacidade máxima (no caso de uma instância bem configurada). Entretanto, o tempo perdido por alguém ou um time na configuração do GitLab pode acabar não compensando no final das contas. Já o GitHub, por outro lado, envolve pagamentos recorrentes e você tem a garantia que seus repositórios estarão quase 100% do tempo no ar.

Comment: uma duvida, se tenho um repositório privado , haveria real necessidade de ter um gitlab no meu servidor de rede local ? Pergunto pois pelo que entendi, antes quando os repo privados nao eram free, fazia sentido voce criar seu proprio ambiente, agora pelo que entendo é mais prático manter tudo lá.